# how do i make the pop up function work which is in vanilla js while response is being fetched from node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, popup, middleware

So upon multiple searches and forums, I tried writing this code for the project(this is my first major project). here I'm trying to accept form inputs from HTML into vanilla js which sends it to backend nodes. I have used routes as different method calls to work on the received data. the database that I'm using is PostgreSQL.
the response data is then checked to display different popups.
the terminal logs show code 304, where the web page is not being updated. the logs are as such:

---

::1 - - [07/May/2023:18:09:32 +0000] "GET /TAS/usersid HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [07/May/2023:18:09:32 +0000] "GET /public/style/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [07/May/2023:18:09:32 +0000] "GET /public/scripts/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [07/May/2023:18:09:32 +0000] "GET /public/scripts/popper.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [07/May/2023:18:09:32 +0000] "GET /public/scripts/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [07/May/2023:18:09:32 +0000] "GET /public/scripts/main.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
**::1 - - [07/May/2023:18:09:38 +0000] "GET /TAS/usersid?teacher-select=SSO&from-time=09%3A00&to-time=10%3A00&department=CMPN HTTP/1.1" 304 -**
::1 - - [07/May/2023:18:09:38 +0000] "GET /public/style/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [07/May/2023:18:09:38 +0000] "GET /public/scripts/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [07/May/2023:18:09:38 +0000] "GET /public/scripts/popper.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [07/May/2023:18:09:38 +0000] "GET /public/scripts/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [07/May/2023:18:09:38 +0000] "GET /public/scripts/main.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -

---

the bold log is where I submit the form inputs and I expect a response as a pop up window [expected page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s74K1.jpg)
instead im being redirected to the main web page.
[redirected page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZicKt.png).
i even tried adding console.log statements to check whether the variables storing the data have received the inputs. to no avail the logs show no such entires of data.

the code below is main.js is a calendar which is used to get the required/desired date to check for that specific date. other data is accepted in HTML form.

```
(function($) {

    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var today = new Date(),
        year = today.getFullYear(),
        month = today.getMonth(),
        monthTag =["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
        day = today.getDate(),
        days = document.getElementsByTagName('td'),
        selectedDay,
        setDate,
        daysLen = days.length;
// options should like '2014-01-01'
    function Calendar(selector, options) {
        this.options = options;
        this.draw();
    }
    

    
    Calendar.prototype.draw  = function() {
        this.getCookie('selected_day');
        this.getOptions();
        this.drawDays();
        var that = this,
            reset = document.getElementById('reset'),
            pre = document.getElementsByClassName('pre-button'),
            next = document.getElementsByClassName('next-button');
            
            pre[0].addEventListener('click', function(){that.preMonth(); });
            next[0].addEventListener('click', function(){that.nextMonth(); });
            reset.addEventListener('click', function(){that.reset(); });
        while(daysLen--) {
            days[daysLen].addEventListener('click', function(){that.clickDay(this); });
        }
    };
    
    Calendar.prototype.drawHeader = function(e) {
        var headDay = document.getElementsByClassName('head-day'),
            headMonth = document.getElementsByClassName('head-month');

            e?headDay[0].innerHTML = e : headDay[0].innerHTML = day;
            headMonth[0].innerHTML = monthTag[month] +" - " + year;        
     };
    
    Calendar.prototype.drawDays = function() {
        var startDay = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay(),

            nDays = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate(),
    
            n = startDay;

        for(var k = 0; k <42; k++) {
            days[k].innerHTML = '';
            days[k].id = '';
            days[k].className = '';
        }

        for(var i  = 1; i <= nDays ; i++) {
            days[n].innerHTML = i; 
            n++;
        }
        
        for(var j = 0; j < 42; j++) {
            if(days[j].innerHTML === ""){
                
                days[j].id = "disabled";
                
            }else if(j === day + startDay - 1){
                if((this.options && (month === setDate.getMonth()) && (year === setDate.getFullYear())) || (!this.options && (month === today.getMonth())&&(year===today.getFullYear()))){
                    this.drawHeader(day);
                    days[j].id = "today";
                }
            }
            if(selectedDay){
                if((j === selectedDay.getDate() + startDay - 1)&&(month === selectedDay.getMonth())&&(year === selectedDay.getFullYear())){
                days[j].className = "selected";
                this.drawHeader(selectedDay.getDate());
                }
            }
        }
    };
    
    Calendar.prototype.clickDay = function(o) {
        var selected = document.getElementsByClassName("selected"),
            len = selected.length;
        if(len !== 0){
            selected[0].className = "";
        }
        o.className = "selected";
        selectedDay = new Date(year, month, o.innerHTML);
        this.drawHeader(o.innerHTML);
        this.setCookie('selected_day', 1);
        
    };





    
    Calendar.prototype.preMonth = function() {
        if(month < 1){ 
            month = 11;
            year = year - 1; 
        }else{
            month = month - 1;
        }
        this.drawHeader(1);
        this.drawDays();
    };
    
    Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function() {
        if(month >= 11){
            month = 0;
            year =  year + 1; 
        }else{
            month = month + 1;
        }
        this.drawHeader(1);
        this.drawDays();
    };
    
    Calendar.prototype.getOptions = function() {
        if(this.options){
            var sets = this.options.split('-');
                setDate = new Date(sets[0], sets[1]-1, sets[2]);
                day = setDate.getDate();
                year = setDate.getFullYear();
                month = setDate.getMonth();
        }
    };
    
     Calendar.prototype.reset = function() {
         month = today.getMonth();
         year = today.getFullYear();
         day = today.getDate();
         this.options = undefined;
         this.drawDays();
     };
    
    Calendar.prototype.setCookie = function(name, expiredays){
        if(expiredays) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expiredays*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" +date.toGMTString();
        }else{
            var expires = "";
        }
        document.cookie = name + "=" + selectedDay + expires + "; path=/";
    };
    
    Calendar.prototype.getCookie = function(name) {
        if(document.cookie.length){
            var arrCookie  = document.cookie.split(';'),
                nameEQ = name + "=";
            for(var i = 0, cLen = arrCookie.length; i < cLen; i++) {
                var c = arrCookie[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                    
                }
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
                    selectedDay =  new Date(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
                }
            }
        }
    };
    var calendar = new Calendar();
    
        
}, false);

})(jQuery);

// pop-up
const fetch =  require('node-fetch')
const form = document.querySelector('teacher-form');
//form.addEventListener("submit",async(event))
//const select = document.querySelector('#teacher-select');
//const submitButton = document.querySelector('#Check1');


form.addEventListener('submit', async(event) => {
    // Prevent the form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get the form data
    //const FROM_DATE =document.getElementById("#options").value;
    const FROM_DATE = "2023-05-03";
    const TO_DATE =document.getElementById("#options").value;
    const T_CODE = document.getElementById('#teacher-select').value;
    const FROM_TIME = document.getElementById('#from-time').value;
    const TO_TIME = document.getElementById('#to-time').value;
    const DEPT = document.getElementById('#department').value;

    //const DATE = document.getElementById('#date').value;
    if (T_CODE.value == '' && T_CODE.value == 'a'){
        warn_popup();
    }
    else{
        const response = await fetch("/TAS/:usersid", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({FROM_DATE,TO_DATE,FROM_TIME,TO_TIME,T_CODE}),
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        if(data.json[0]['available']===true){
           popup();
        }
        else{
            error_popup();
        }
       
    }
});
    

function popup(){
    //if condition for available is true then run this pop up
    {
    swal({
        title: "Yes!",
        text: "The Faculty is available!",
        icon: "success",
        button: "Ok!",
      });}
    }
function error_popup(){
      { //if condition false run this pop up
        swal({
            title: "Sorry!",
            text: "The Faculty is not available!",
            icon: "error",
            button: "Try Again!",
          });} 
    
}
function warn_popup(){
    { // if none of the value is selected for teachers
        swal({
            title: "Warning!",
            text: "Please first select the above details!",
            icon: "warning",
            button: "Try Again!",
          });} 
}
```

the code below is in index.js which i'm using as backend node js file.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { request } = require('http')
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks')
var multer = require('multer')
var upload = multer()
const app = express()
const db = require('./queries')
const helmet = require("helmet");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const port = 5500

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended:true,
    })
)
app.get('/',(request,response)=> {
    response.json({info:'node.js,express'})
})
app.use(cors());
app.use(
  helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({
    policy: "cross-origin",
  })
);
app.use(morgan("common"));
// have res.render work with html files
app.set('view engine', 'html');
// when res.render works with html files, have it use nunjucks to do so
app.engine('html', nunjucks.render);
nunjucks.configure('../blah/views/index.html', { noCache: true });
app.use(upload.array()); 
app.use(express.static("../blah/"))
const router = express.Router();
app.use('/', router)
router.get('/TAS/usersid', function (req,res,next) {
    res.render('index', {});
})
app.get('/users', db.getUsers)
app.use(express.json());
app.get('/TAS/usersid', db.getUserById)
app.post('/usersin', db.createUser)
app.put('/usersup', db.updateUser)
app.delete('/usersdl', db.deleteUser)

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

rest is the queries which work on the requested input data.

```
const { request } = require('http') 
const fs = require('fs')
const weekday = ["SUNDAY","MONDAY","TUESDAY","WEDNESDAY","THURSDAY","FRIDAY","SATURDAY"]

const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'postgres',
    host:'localhost',
    database:'MiniProjS4',
    password:'Password',
    port:'5432'
})
 
const getUsers = (request, response) => {
  var {FROM_DATE,TO_DATE,FROM_TIME,TO_TIME,T_CODE} = (request.body)
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM CMPN_UPDATE_TABLE WHERE FROM_DATE=$1 AND TO_DATE=$2 AND FROM_TIME>=$3 AND TO_TIME<=$4 AND T_CODE=$5 ', [FROM_DATE,TO_DATE,FROM_TIME,TO_TIME,T_CODE], (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error
        }
        if (results.rows.length === 0) {
          getUserById(request, response);
        }
      response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
  }
  const getUserById = async (request, response) => {
    const { FROM_DATE, TO_DATE , FROM_TIME, TO_TIME, T_CODE,DEPT } = request.body;
    const d = new Date(FROM_DATE);
    const tablename = T_CODE + "_" + weekday[d.getDay()];
    
    const query = `SELECT AVAILABLE,LOC FROM ${tablename} WHERE FROM_TIME>=$1 AND TO_TIME<=$2`;
  
    pool.query(query, [FROM_TIME, TO_TIME], (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      response.status(200).json(results.rows);
    });  
    console.log(tablename);
  }
  
  
  
  const createUser = (request, response) => {
    const { FROM_DATE,TO_DATE,FROM_TIME,TO_TIME,T_CODE,AVAILABLE,REASON } = request.body
  
    pool.query('INSERT INTO CMPN_UPDATE_TABLE VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7)', [FROM_DATE,TO_DATE,FROM_TIME,TO_TIME,T_CODE,AVAILABLE,REASON], (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      response.status(201).send(`User added with ID: $5`)
    })
  }
  
  const updateUser = (request, response) => {
    const id = parseInt(request.params.id)
    const { FROM_DATE,TO_DATE,FROM_TIME,TO_TIME,T_CODE,AVAILABLE,REASON} = request.body
  
    pool.query(
      'UPDATE CMPN_UPDATE_TABLE SET FROM_TIME = $3, TO_TIME = $4,AVAILABLE=$6,REASON=$7 WHERE T_CODE = $5 and FROM_DATE=$1  and TO_DATE=$2',
      [FROM_DATE,TO_DATE,FROM_TIME,TO_TIME,T_CODE,AVAILABLE,REASON],
      (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          throw error
        }
        response.status(200).send(`User modified with ID: ${id}`)
      }
    )
  }
  
  const deleteUser = (request, response) => {
    const { from_date,to_date,t_code} = request.body
  
    pool.query('DELETE FROM cmpn_update_table WHERE d_code = $3  and from_date=$1  and to_date=$2', [from_date,to_date,t_code], (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      response.status(200).send(`User deleted with ID: ${id}`)
    })
  }
  
  module.exports = {
    getUsers,
    getUserById,
    createUser,
    updateUser,
    deleteUser,
  }
```

the code is incomplete as im trying to add function one at a time.

i tried checking the console and midddleware but the instead the landing webpage is being sent as response instead of the pop-up functions.

Comment: thank you for your advice. i have made the edits and added image links of the desired outputs and actual ones.though I suppose i have still made some mistakes